# Spring REST Jackson Object deserialization fails with hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, jackson, spring-boot

I've narrowed down my problem to some interaction between hibernate annotations and the object deserialization. I'm using spring boot and hibernate for storing data into a postgres DB.
Deserialization is done by jackson and all three examples use a JSON string that is valid and looks a bit like: `{"id":-1,"alertType":"someType","alertInfos":[{"id":-1,"description":"somedescription"}],...}`

What I have is a class with a reference to another class:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to AlertInfo
@OneToMany(mappedBy="alert", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<AlertInfo> alertInfos;
```

As soon this is deserialized I'll get:

> Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: model.ressource.Alert["alertInfos"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
>
> Note that something decided `ArrayList` to be the implementation of the `List` interface

Deserialization works if I drop the hibernate annotation and change to `ArrayList`:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to AlertInfo
//@OneToMany(mappedBy="alert", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private ArrayList<AlertInfo> alertInfos;
```

Of course I can't store it to the Database anymore since hibernate doesn't know the relations.

Can anyone tell me why option three won't work?

This leaves the logical option which doesn't even start the Application:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to AlertInfo
@OneToMany(mappedBy="alert", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private ArrayList<AlertInfo> alertInfos;
```

This causes:

> Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: model.ressource.Alert.alertInfos

To whom it might concern: The AlertInfo.class's side:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "alert_id")
private Alert alert;
```

How can I fix the last one so it will work like intended?

## EDIT 1:

Requested Entities:

Alert.class

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alerts", schema = "ressource_db", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }) })
@NamedQuery(name = "Alert.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Alert a")
public class Alert implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ressource_db.id_seq", name = "AlertIdSequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AlertIdSequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "original_id")
    private String identifier;

    @Transient
    private String sender;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Geometry geometry;

    @Column(name = "last_edit_date_time")
    private Timestamp lastEditDateTime;

    @Column(name = "msg_status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "msg_type")
    private String msgType;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = GeometryDeserializer.class)
    private Point position;

    private String scope;

    @Column(name = "sent_date_time")
    private Timestamp sent;

    @Column(name = "version_count")
    private Long versionCount;

    @Column(name = "alert_msg")
    private String alertmsg;

    @Column(name = "is_current")
    private boolean isCurrent;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to AlertInfo
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "alert", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AlertInfo> alertInfos;

    public Alert() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastEditDateTime() {
        return lastEditDateTime;
    }

    public void setLastEditDateTime(Timestamp lastEditDateTime) {
        this.lastEditDateTime = lastEditDateTime;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMsgType() {
        return msgType;
    }

    public void setMsgType(String msgType) {
        this.msgType = msgType;
    }

    public Point getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Point position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public Timestamp getSent() {
        return sent;
    }

    public void setSent(Timestamp sent) {
        this.sent = sent;
    }

    public Long getVersionCount() {
        return versionCount;
    }

    public void setVersionCount(Long versionCount) {
        this.versionCount = versionCount;
    }

    public String getAlertmsg() {
        return alertmsg;
    }

    public void setAlertmsg(String alertmsg) {
        this.alertmsg = alertmsg;
    }

    public boolean isCurrent() {
        return isCurrent;
    }

    public void setCurrent(boolean isCurrent) {
        this.isCurrent = isCurrent;
    }

    public List<AlertInfo> getAlertInfos() {
        return this.alertInfos;
    }

    public void setAlertInfos(List<AlertInfo> alertInfos) {
        this.alertInfos = alertInfos;
    }

    public AlertInfo addAlertInfo(AlertInfo alertInfo) {
        if (getAlertInfos() == null) {
            this.alertInfos = new ArrayList<AlertInfo>();
        }

        getAlertInfos().add(alertInfo);
        alertInfo.setAlert(this);

        return alertInfo;
    }

    public AlertInfo removeAlertInfo(AlertInfo alertInfo) {
        getAlertInfos().remove(alertInfo);
        alertInfo.setAlert(null);

        return alertInfo;
    }

}
```

AlertInfo.class

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alert_infos", schema = "ressource_db", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }) })
@NamedQuery(name = "AlertInfo.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AlertInfo a")
public class AlertInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "ressource_db.id_seq", name = "AlertInfoIdSequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AlertInfoIdSequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "event_category")
    private ArrayList<String> category;

    @Transient
    private String event;

    private String urgency;

    private String severity;

    private String certainty;

    @Transient
    private List<CapAlertInfoEventCode> eventCodes;

    @Transient
    private Timestamp effective;

    @Transient
    private Timestamp expires;

    @Transient
    private String senderName;

    private String headline;

    private String description;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Alert
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "alert_id")
    private Alert alert;

    public AlertInfo() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCertainty() {
        return certainty;
    }

    public void setCertainty(String certainty) {
        this.certainty = certainty;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(String severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    public String getUrgency() {
        return urgency;
    }

    public void setUrgency(String urgency) {
        this.urgency = urgency;
    }

    public List<CapAlertInfoEventCode> getEventCodes() {
        return eventCodes;
    }

    public void setEventCodes(List<CapAlertInfoEventCode> eventCodes) {
        this.eventCodes = eventCodes;
    }

    public Timestamp getEffective() {
        return effective;
    }

    public void setEffective(Timestamp effective) {
        this.effective = effective;
    }

    public Timestamp getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }

    public void setExpires(Timestamp expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }

    public String getSenderName() {
        return senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(String senderName) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(ArrayList<String> category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Alert getAlert() {
        return alert;
    }

    public void setAlert(Alert alert) {
        this.alert = alert;
    }

}
```

Comment: please post whole entities here

Comment: Added the entities to the original question's description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issues are no longer the case with the newest spring boot release. It works now if I have the annotations like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "alert", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<AlertInfo> alertInfos;
```